# How to replace values in a column with zeros in .txt file using bash

Tags: bash

I have a tab delimited txt file containing 3 columns, like this:

[image]

I simply want to replace all values in the middle column with zero's, so it looks like this:

[image]

I got only as far as that I might need to use sed, but I have know idea how to specify the second column. This is what I found so far:

```
sed -i 's/column2/0/g' Con_Dec_0.txt
```

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Thanks to @socowi for letting me know on TAB delimited files so adding solution as per that now.

For tab delimited:

```
awk -v FS='[[:space:]]+' 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {$2="0";$1=$1} 1' Input_file
```

To save output into Input_file try following:

```
awk -v FS='[[:space:]]+' '{$2="0"} 1' Input_file | column -t > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

---

---

Since you have not posted samples in text formats so not sure what is the delimiter of your Input_file, could you please try following.

```
awk '{$2="0"} 1' Input_file
```

To save output into Input_file itself use following if Happy with above.

```
awk '{$2="0"} 1' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

Comment: OP said `I have a tab delimited txt file`.

Comment: @Socowi, Thank you for letting know, will edit it now.

Comment: I'm wondering why this answer got upvoted so much and even accepted. The input is tab-delimited, but this answer uses any whitespace to split fields – spaces in fields will be misinterpreted. Also, the output is no longer tab-delimited.

Comment: @Socowi, For my answer I would say, OP's Input_file doesn't look exact tab delimited and 2nd- since it was asked to put tab delimited output so I used column command in it, if OP says exact spaces should be same then I would add another approach here too. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. `since it was asked to put tab delimited output so I used column command`. Um... the `column` command doesn't use tabs; it uses spaces to align the columns.

Comment: @Socowi, right since tabs doesn't look fixed so taken spaces to get it right. Please do lemme know if I missed something here by doing this $2 will be same for all lines.

Comment: Woops I missed that. I think in the end it won't be a problem for me if it is tab or space delimited. However, if I do want to get the output tab-delimited. What should I use instead of the line provided?

Comment: @Annelies, that column command should give output tab delimited please check it once and lemme know then

Comment: Ok, when I open the file in excel, it seems that the fields are separated by spaces instead of tabs. Or should I find this out in another way?

Comment: @Annelies, ok please try mine EDIT could command's OR one now?

Comment: @Socowi, Request you could you please check my EDIT solution and lemme know if that looks fine to you, your opinion matters to me, thank you again.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I'm very happy about your improvements. The very first command should work for this particular input I think. However, the command is still a bit more complicated than would have to be. For instance `-F '\t'` would be more robust and shorter than `-v FS='[[:space:]]+'`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
awk -F '[[:space:]]+' '{ print $1 "\t" 0 "\t" $2 } ' foo.txt
```

Or even shorter like this:

```
awk -F '[[:space:]]+' '{ $2=0 } 1' foo.txt
```

This should work regardless of a tab or whitespace separated CSV file.

From the manual (any run of spaces and/or tabs and/or newlines is treated as a field separator), so you might drop the `-F separator`. This will result in the answer posted below, i.e:

```
  awk '{ $2=0 } 1' foo.txt
```

Edit: Need to change `*` (single or more matches) to `+` (one or more matches).

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` is possible.

```
sed 's/\t[^\t]*/\t0/' yourFile
```

`[^\t]*` matches as many non-tab characters as possible, that is, the 2nd field because we required that there is a `\t` in front of it. Note the missing `/g` at the end – we only replace the first occurrence, that is, the 2nd column.

However, for the general case of replacing column *n* with a value it is easier to use an `awk` script.

```
awk -F '\t' '{OFS="\t"; $2=0; print}' yourFile
```

`-F` sets the field separator for the input.
`OFS` sets the field separator for the output.
The part inside `{...}` is executed for each line.
`$2=...` changes the 2nd column.
`print` prints all fields using the output separator.

Comment: This will succeed also for more columns which might not be intended.

Comment: No it won't. Note the missing `/g` at the end (as I explicitly pointed out in the answer). Try it yourself: `sed 's/\t[^\t]*/\t0/' <<< $'a\tb\tc'`.

Comment: Sorry @Socowi: I mean it will not explicitly fail for CSV files with more than 3 columns. But this should probably be checked before.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `it will not explicitly fail`. Is there a problem? Do you have an example input?

Comment: Well, I think your answer is fine. "middle column" is fine, e.g. 2nd match, if always 3 columns are in the file. But this is something the OP probably needs to assure.

Comment: The `sed` script also works if there are only two columns, or 100 columns -- it really doesn't matter. However, it won't work if there is only one column. But I think that's ok as OP said `replace` and not `insert`.